# Иллюстрация причин закрытия с помощью puzzle-аналогии

Tags: поддержка, перевод-содержимого

Наткнулся на удачную аналогию между головоломками и вопросами Stack Overflow, которая позволяет представить вопросы и проиллюстрировать причины закрытия в виде картинок.

[image: puzzle]

При обсуждении причин закрытия, чтобы показать их желаемое использование, можно или напрямую [ссылку на сообщение дать](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/137096) или (если интерес есть) можно перевод текста в виде ответа к этому сообщению добавить и ссылаться на него.

Comment: или даже добавить в справку переведенный пост с картинками

Comment: Отличный пример, надо перевести.

Answer (score 1):

#### Причина закрытия: непонятна суть вопроса

> Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Пример неясного вопроса: *"Как соединить четыре фрагмента головоломки?"*:

> [image: "How should I put these 4 pieces together?"]

<sup>из [сообщения @jmac♦︎](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/137096)</sup>

Не хватает информации для ответа. [Иногда сообществу требуется больше информации, чтобы помочь вам в решении вашей проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).